# How to get the id of a toolbar menu item?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-toolbar

I am new to android development, C# and have no experience to components stuffs. I am using Xamarin android and currently experiencing problem with the toolbar menu items. What i want is that when one of the item is pressed, it calls another function. Currently i dont know how to get the id of the item. Below is my code.

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            Type thing = item.GetType();
            String id = FindViewById <thing> (V002.Resource.Id.menu_edit);

            if (id == "menu_edit") { 
            }
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Action selected: " + item.TitleFormatted,
                ToastLength.Short).Show();
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            Type thing = item.GetType();
            String id = item.ItemId;
            switch(id){
                case Resource.Id.menu_edit:
                // - Do whatever you want to do here
                return true;
            }
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Action selected: " + item.TitleFormatted,
                ToastLength.Short).Show();
            default:
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: when i try  " String id = item.getItemId();", I get the following : Error CS1061: Type `Android.Views.IMenuItem' does not contain a definition for `getItemId' and no extension method `getItemId' of type `Android.Views.IMenuItem' could be found.

Comment: Oddly enough, item.ItemId gives you an integer, not a string

Comment: even Resource.Id.menu_edit also gives you an integer, need to change the variable datatype